# Using variable names for input and output files in dd

Tags: shell-script, partition, dd, variable, disk

I'm creating a bash script that will allow me to clone disks, and allow the user to select the input disk to clone and the output disk to clone to. I've almost finished, but I just have one hang up. dd doesn't recognize the variable names for the disks. Supposing srcDisk and destDisk are defined as existing disks (these variables are called elsewhere in my script and work with utilities such as sfdisk and fdisk), here is what I've tried:

```
    dd if=/dev/$srcDisk of=/dev/$destDisk
```

I have also wondered if I need to specify partitions, and since number of partitions may vary, I tried a do until loop, with the iterator variable (i) specifying the partition number. This still didn't work:

```
until [ $i -gt srcPartNum ]
do
    dd if=/dev/$srcDisk$i of=/dev/$destDisk$i conv=notrunc & pid=$!
    while kill -USR1 $pid; do sleep 1; done
done
```

I'm not sure how to fix this or any workarounds.

Comment: Have you tried placing the variable names within quotes?  ("$srcDisk")

Comment: Try echoing the variables to the command line: is it possible that $srcDisk and/or $destDisk have more than just "sdx" as a value, but contain something like "/dev/sdx", making the command you issued `dd if=/dev/$srcDisk of=/dev/$destDisk` look like `dd if=/dev//dev/sda of=/dev//dev/sdb`

Comment: How are you setting the variables? Are they set outside the script, or inside? If set outside, are you `export`ing them, or passing as `srcDisk=foo /path/to/myscript`, or neither? What error are you getting when the script runs?

Comment: So it looks like it's working after putting the variable names between quotes. Thanks! The variables are read in from user input within the script.

Comment: EDIT: It is not working, even after putting in the quotes. What it gives me is:
/usr/local/bin/clonedisk.sh: line 37: [: srcPartNum: integer expression expected
/usr/local/bin/clonedisk.sh: line 41: 12521 User defined signal 1   dd if=/dev/"$srcDisk" of=/dev/"$destDisk" conv=notrunc

The variables are read into the script from user input. I input them in as mmcblk0 and sda respectively.

Comment: I echoed those variables and the are correct. The interesting thing is when I declare each of the variables straight in the terminal, and then run the dd command thus (without quotes):
dd if=/dev/$srcDisk of=/dev/$destDisk
it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

First off, your `dd` will be desperately slow. Use this instead

```
cat "/dev/$srcDisk" >"/dev/$destDisk"
```

Your source and destination disks must not be in use when you copy them.

Without seeing an error message or other result from your existing script i can't tell you why `dd` isn't recognising your variables. Aside from not quoting the variables there's nothing syntactically wrong with your snippet. You could maybe echo out the variables' values at the point you copy the disk, or add `set -x` a little way above the problematic piece of code.

As an aside, have you investigated scripting something like Clonezilla?

Comment: Or `pv` if you want to see a pretty progress bar.

Comment: Hm, yeah dd does take a long time. The only thing is the main application for this for me is to clone the system disk, while it's in the device (Raspberry Pi). Will dd mess up if either of the disks are in use?

Comment: @MattR you can't copy a disk like this while it's in use

Comment: @MattR To clarify roaima's comment: if you copy a disk while it's in use, the copy process will succeed, but what it'll copy is an inconsistent state of the disk that's very likely to have corrupted data, either in obvious or non-obvious ways.